# Check in luggage on flights between London and Edinburgh

Tags: air-travel, luggage, london, check-in, edinburgh

I have checked 5 flights between London and Edinburgh.

All of them says Check in baggage 0 kgs, Cabin baggage 10 kgs.

Is this the case for every flight between these two places?

Comment: What website are you using - it might well be that for the cheapest fare between them that is the case, but you can pay extra for a checked in bag.

Comment: Yes, I looked flights with cheapest rates.. thanks. This answer my question.. can you tell me how much I might have yo pay??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It really depends on the airline and the fare. The best the to do is to go to the airline website directly, search for a flight, and to review the options they present you with. There will be different fares and options to purchase checked bags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays many of the short-haul flights (and some of the long-haul flights) have a lowest fare that does not include any checked luggage.

This is usually shown quite prominently during booking (especially on the airline’s own website), with incentives to book more expensive fares which include checked-in luggage and/or other advantages, usually centred around flexibility (modifiable or refundable fares), number of frequent flyer miles earned, priority treatment, and so on.

You usually always have the option to add a checked-in luggage allowance to your booking, though:

- the cost is usually slightly higher than the fare difference between the lowest no-hold-luggage-included and the next more expensive fare which includes luggage
- it is nearly always a lot more expensive to pay for the hold luggage at the airport and/or at the last minute. You definitely want to buy the allowance online in advance.